# Gaussian Smoothing Error and "Hard Analysis" Bounds

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $p \in (0,\infty)$. Consider a function $f \in L^p([0,1])$, and let $$\phi_\epsilon(x) = \frac{\exp(-x^2/2\epsilon^2)}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon^2}}$$ denote a $0$-mean Gaussian of variance $\epsilon$ (this could be changed to any other of mollifier, if more convenient). I want to bound the error of smoothing $f$ by convolving with $\phi_\epsilon$, that is, to bound
$$\left| \int_{[0,1]} f^p - \int_{[0,1]} (f * \phi_\epsilon)^p \right|$$ it terms of $\epsilon$ and, if necessary, some additional assumptions on $f$.

Basically, I know $f * \phi_\epsilon \to f$ in $L^p$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, but I want a "hard" rate on this convergence.

More generally, can anyone suggest a good text for a "hard" approach to real analysis, measure theory, and functional analysis? I have an undergraduate background in these areas, but my courses largely have stuck to "soft" analysis (e.g., proving convergence while avoiding explicit bounds). Lately, I have been working in Computer Science, where explicit error bounds are desired.